# displaying the output in the label

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display the output in the label, and keep a records of all the data entered previously. In some sort of drop down menu perhaps?

How can I keep all of the data entered?

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DatabaseSQLApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnStrings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string firstName;
            firstName = textBox1.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(firstName);

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In btnStrings_Click, add this line:

```
label1.Text += Environment.NewLine+firstName;
```

just make sure you let enough room for the label to grow

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, a Label is the wrong UI component to use.  From your Tool box on the designer, drop a ListBox onto your application.  From there you can do this in your btnStrings event handler:

```
    private void btnStrings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Sweet, alex! thats exactly what I was trying to acheive. I appreciate it. Now - I got my application to work.

Comment: This code looks a little sloppy. How can I put all these together to make the code look better? - `string ArtistName, SongTitle, Source, Url;
            ArtistName = textBox1.Text;
            SongTitle = textBox2.Text;
            Source = textBox3.Text;
            Url = textBox4.Text;
            Database.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + textBox2 + textBox3 + textBox4);`